# Reading incoming bluetooth data to another app

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a fitness tracker that syncs with a phone app. 
I am interested in retrieving the incoming data from the fitness tracker to the android app during the syncing process.

Any way to go about this?

anyway to the retrieve the api of the fitness tracker? its not publicly released.
I am trying to make my app integrate with the fitness tracker.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and here is why:

When two devices connect over Bluetooth one acts as a server and the other as a client. When the server creates its `BluetoothServerSocket` it provides a string (it can be the application's package) and a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID).

On the other side,

> when the client attempts to connect with this device (the server), it carries a
>   UUID that uniquely identifies the service with which it wants to
>   connect. **These UUIDs must match in order for the connection to be accepted.**

You can read all of these [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth).